# Q Language for usage in KDB

Tags: kdb

I was challenged to either learn Q language, or to continue analyzing the query responses with Python.

So learning Q would give advantage of small traffic generated, while the query response to process with Python would be in the range of 160GB a day.

Do you have recommendations on programming in Q, especially dealing with tables?

All the manuals I find are too generic. The only one which is somewhat close to what I need is the vendor's manual, but it is pretty old, from 2009.

[Abridged Q Language Manual, 2009.03.16](https://legaldocumentation.kx.com/q/d/q.htm)

Specifically the idea is to send such a query to the KDB server that most of the analysis to be already done by the server, and what is left to be analyzed to be not so much, or perfectly, just to dump the results on the disk and to prepare the next query.

Is there a crash course, or at least more up-to-date manual?

Comment: https://code.kx.com/q4m3/ or qTips by Nick Psaris are good places to start when learning q

Answer (score 3):

There are many of us kdb+ devs here on SO who are happy to help with any specific questions you have, if they’re tagged with kdb.

If you’re looking for a “crash course”, AquaQ offer a [free kdb+ bootcamp taster](https://kdbtraining.aquaq.co.uk/shop/kdb-taster/) that may provide the basics required to get going. (Full disclaimer, I’m an employee of AquaQ). The taster includes basic operations in q, some qSQL querying and connecting to a q session via a web browser. There is also the opportunity to purchase the full bootcamp course if that’s an option for you.

All of this, alongside the [Kx reference site](https://code.kx.com), should set you on your way.